# Formula to calculate height $x$ depth cutting area of a band saw with $4$ wheels

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I need help, I am trying to create a formula to calculate the height ($H$) for a bandsaw design.

- The blade length ($L$) shown in red color, desired cutting depth (W), and wheel diameters $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ will all be known.
- The outer edge of the wheels will always align outward horizontally and inward vertically (see 'Cutting Area').
- $A$, $B$, $C$ diameters will be the same diameter with each other and are all smaller than $D$.

I appreciate the help, I am stuck on this one.[image]

Comment: We need 1) the relative positionning in height=ordinate of the center of wheel D with respect to the center of wheel A : is there an horizontal tangent common to circles A and D ? 2) your confirmation that length H is the length the left hand side (colored in red) segment (not including a rounded part).

Comment: Everything needed to solve the problem is given in the picture.  He wants a relationship between $A,B,C,D,H$ and $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look at the attached picture annotated.
[image]

Firstly, the inclination angle $a$ can be calculated from the difference in diameters of wheels $A$ and $D$.

$$\sin(a) = \frac{D}{W-D-A},$$
where I use the capital letters to represent the wheel labels and also their radii.

Next, compute $b = \pi-(\pi/2-a) = \pi/2+a$.
Then, the length of the arc around $D$ is given by
$$\text{arc}_{D} = D \times b.$$

Now, as we move from segment $CD$ to segment $AB$ (counter-clockwise), we traverse a total angle of $\pi$.  Therefore,
$$c = \pi - b = \pi - (\pi/2 + a) = \pi/2-a.$$
And, the arc around this wheel is
$$\text{arc}_{A} = A \times (\pi/2-a).$$

Finally, the diagonal segment between $A$ and $D$ is
$$\text{diag} = \sqrt{(W-A-D)^2-D^2}.$$

Therefore, the total belt distance is
$$L = 2H+(W-B-C) + \pi/2 C + \pi/2 B + \text{arc}_{A} + \text{arc}_{D} + A + D + \text{diag}.$$

Comment: I left out $\pi/2$ times $B$ and $C$ (top two corners).  Please see updated formula.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Solving for H will then be:

=(-(−−)-/2-/2-arc-arc---diag)/2

Comment: Doug, I need some more help because I tried to use your formula and ran into trouble in Excel when trying to create it. Let me show some numbers:
Solving for H
L=170
W=48
A=12
B=12
C=12
D=20

To calculate the sin(): =SIN(RADIANS(D/(W-D-A)))
I am not sure with the calculation of b, would it be: SIN(RADIANS(D/(W-D-A)))
If you can help me regarding how to do this in Excel I would appreciate it.

Comment: @MarkMain, with those values, I don't think the angle $a$ will be in range.  It's difficult to know without drawing a picture scaled with those values.  You might need to increase $W$.

Comment: @MarkMain, NVM.  In my formula, it would be radius, not diameter.  So, wherever you have $A$,$B$, etc. replace with $A/2$, $B/2$, etc.  I'm getting an angle $a = 0.3$ radians.